# No way to rotate username in a User Credentials secret

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-secrets-manager

We have some username+password values stored in IBM secret manager, we need to rotate the username along with the password and the UI in IBM cloud-only allows you to rotate the password.

Tried using the CLI (command below), but [the docs](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/secrets-manager?topic=secrets-manager-manual-rotation&interface=cli#manual-rotate-user-credentials-cli) only show updating I the password, even though I we're updating body I here I.

```
ibmcloud secrets-manager secret-update --action rotate --id "xxxx" --secret-type username_password --body '{"username": "xxxx", "password":"xxx"}' --output json --service-url https://xxxxxx.xxx.secrets-manager.appdomain.cloud
```

Is updating usernames possible in IBM Secret Manager for 'username_password' types? or should we just use JSON key-value secrets for our username+passwords when changing the username is a possibility?

Comment: I am trying to understand the use case of rotating a username. Why is the username changed in addition to the password? Usually "rotating a secret" means changing the password (only).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the username of your User-credentials secret. Consider it like email + password, you can only rotate the password, not the email. Not supported.